# get() returned more than one Item -- it returned 2! - Django foreign key query

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have table A which has a column `details_id` which is a foreign key pointing to the primary key in another table B in Django.

```
class A(models.Model):
    per_id = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    hobby = models.TextField()
    details_id = models.ForeignKey(B, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True) # the foreign key

class B(models.Model):
    details_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) # the primary key
    fav_food = models.TextField()
```

I am trying to fetch the `details_id` in table B, from the `per_id` in table A

```
qs=qs.filter(per_id="2398") # this gives me the queryset for the person with per_id=2398
details=qs[0].details_id.details_id # this line gives the error
```

The problem is that since there are ***2 entries*** in the table B which have the same ***details_id***, I am getting the following error -

```
get() returned more than one B -- it returned 2!
```

**Table A** -

[image]

**Table B** -

[image]

And I want to retrieve both of the values

How can I do that?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with your database. What is supposed to be the primary key in B, isn't unique. I don't know how this can happen. Are you mapping Django on top of a database table created by something else?

If you define your model in the normal way you don't explicitly define a primary key at all and Django creates one for you and guarantees its uniqueness.

To get the duplicates:

```
b_list = list( B.objects.filter( details_id=2) ) # len(b_list) will be 2
```

Comment: I am using another a second preexisting sqlite database and these are the models that I created for it

Comment: Also, I want to access the details_id using that queryset (qs) that I have created earlier, not by making a new filter query on the table B as I would not have the details_id for that

Comment: Any idea how that can be done?

Comment: I want the details_id corresponding to the per_id 2398

Comment: How should I get the details_id in the first place to give it to the ```B.objects.filter()``` command?

Comment: There is something wrong with your db. As author of this answer said: Having two identical primary key shouldn't be possible. You need to remove one of them or change pk of it.

Comment: Are you saying that if I make some other column the primary key the command will work?

Comment: I need to run `details=qs[0].details_id.details_id` to retrive the details_id

Comment: Will it return multiple values if any other column is made as the Primary Key?